# How to subset data based on more than 1 condition

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am looking to subset a gene dataset, selecting genes based on their machine learning class (labels 0-2) and their loci/rssnp ID.

My data looks like this:

```
Chr  Start   End     rssnp1        Type    gene     ML.prediction
1   1244733 1244734 rs2286773   LD_SNP  ACE                0
1   1257536 1257436 rs333333    LD_SNP  CPEB4              1
1   1252336 1252336 rs2286773   Sentinel    CPEB4          2
1   1252343 1252343 rs333333    LD_SNP  CPEB4              0
1   1254841 1254841 rs333333    LD_SNP  BRCA2              3
1   1256703 1267404 rs444444    LD_SNP  HER2               0
1   1269246 1269246 rs301159    LD_SNP  CPEB4              1
1   1370168 1370168 rs301159    LD_SNP  GLUT2              0 
1   1371824 1371824 r4444444    LD_SNP  GLUPA1             1
1   1372591 1372591 rs111111    LD_SNP  GLUPA1             1
1   1372591 1372591 rs111111    LD_SNP  GLUPA2             1
1   1372591 1372591 rs111111    LD_SNP  GLUPA3             1
```

My output would be like this:

```
Chr  Start   End     rssnp1        Type    gene     ML.prediction
1   1244733 1244734 rs2286773   LD_SNP  ACE                0
1   1252336 1252336 rs2286773   Sentinel    CPEB4          2
1   1257536 1257436 rs333333    LD_SNP  CPEB4              1
1   1252343 1252343 rs333333    LD_SNP  CPEB4              0
1   1254841 1254841 rs333333    LD_SNP  BRCA2              3
1   1269246 1269246 rs301159    LD_SNP  CPEB4              1
1   1370168 1370168 rs301159    LD_SNP  GLUT2              0
1   1256703 1267404 rs444444    LD_SNP  HER2               0 
1   1371824 1371824 r4444444    LD_SNP  GLUPA1             1
```

So it only selects genes with prediction 0, and then selects that gene's surrounding genes based on the matching rssnp1.

I have tried using lapply() and order but I am a beginnger and struggling to make anything that works at all, so any guidance on what functions I should be using, or how to set my conditions in lapply() would be appreciated.

Currently I have working, getting all rssnp1s for each gene with a 0 prediction in excel, then ordering my file with

```
order <- df[order(match(df$rssnp1, target_order)),]
```

target order being me inputting hundreds of rssnp1 ids manually, but is there any way quicker than this?

Comment: Can you `dput(head(df, 12))` or similar to provide a sample of your data?

Answer (score 2):

I’d perform a two-step selection:

1. Find variants with prediction = 0:

   ```
   prediction_snps = df$rssnp1[df$ML.prediction == 0]
   ```
2. Subset your data based on SNPs:

   ```
   result = df[df$rssnp1 %in% prediction_snps, ]
   ```

You can also achieve similar results using dplyr or data.table. Either way, `lapply` and `order` aren’t needed here, and don’t really help.

Answer (score 2):

Note that there seems to be a mistake in your sample data where `rs444444` is different from `r4444444`; therefore the expected output doesn't match your input data.

That aside, here is a `dplyr` option

```
df %>%
    group_by(rssnp1) %>%
    filter(any(ML.prediction == 0)) %>%
    ungroup()
## A tibble: 8 x 7
#    Chr   Start     End rssnp1    Type     gene  ML.prediction
#  <int>   <int>   <int> <fct>     <fct>    <fct>         <int>
#1     1 1244733 1244734 rs2286773 LD_SNP   ACE               0
#2     1 1257536 1257436 rs333333  LD_SNP   CPEB4             1
#3     1 1252336 1252336 rs2286773 Sentinel CPEB4             2
#4     1 1252343 1252343 rs333333  LD_SNP   CPEB4             0
#5     1 1254841 1254841 rs333333  LD_SNP   BRCA2             3
#6     1 1256703 1267404 rs444444  LD_SNP   HER2              0
#7     1 1269246 1269246 rs301159  LD_SNP   CPEB4             1
#8     1 1370168 1370168 rs301159  LD_SNP   GLUT2             0
```

Explanation: Group entries by`rssnp1` and then retain only those groups where at least one entry has `ML.prediction == 0`.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Chr  Start   End     rssnp1        Type    gene     ML.prediction
1   1244733 1244734 rs2286773   LD_SNP  ACE                0
1   1257536 1257436 rs333333    LD_SNP  CPEB4              1
1   1252336 1252336 rs2286773   Sentinel    CPEB4          2
1   1252343 1252343 rs333333    LD_SNP  CPEB4              0
1   1254841 1254841 rs333333    LD_SNP  BRCA2              3
1   1256703 1267404 rs444444    LD_SNP  HER2               0
1   1269246 1269246 rs301159    LD_SNP  CPEB4              1
1   1370168 1370168 rs301159    LD_SNP  GLUT2              0
1   1371824 1371824 r4444444    LD_SNP  GLUPA1             1
1   1372591 1372591 rs111111    LD_SNP  GLUPA1             1
1   1372591 1372591 rs111111    LD_SNP  GLUPA2             1
1   1372591 1372591 rs111111    LD_SNP  GLUPA3             1", header = T)
```